# Excel to MS Access connection: Issues with with space in connection string

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have been able to successfully connect my excel to MS access, and using the connection, I am able to push and pull data to and from excel to Access DB. However, I noticed, if my connection string has space in between like mentioned below, I am unable to establish the connection. Is there any way around it?

Connection string with space

```
Set oADODBCon = New ADODB.Connection
    oADODBCon.Open Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\XYZ-123\0123\ABC 2020 Test Operations\MyDb.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;
```

I have tried using single quotes in my connection string as below but it still didn't work

```
Set oADODBCon = New ADODB.Connection
    oADODBCon.Open Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='\\XYZ-123\0123\ABC 2020 Test Operations\MyDb.accdb';Persist Security Info=False;
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
oADODBCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\XYZ-123\0123\ABC 2020 Test Operations\MyDb.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
```